# After upgrading to Capybara 2.1 and Poltergeist 1.5.0, we're getting ActionController::RoutingError for "/my/image.png" in JS tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

We upgraded from Capybara 1.1.4 and Poltergeist 1.0.2. phantomjs stayed at version 1.8.1 throughout.

JS tests that rendered pages with e.g. `<img src="/my/image.png">` would fail with the above error, where they didn't fail before.

That file is indeed not present. It's a fake path generated for tests, and making it into a real file is sadly not trivial (but should eventually be done).

Answer (score 1):

Our solution/workaround was to configure Poltergeist not to render images:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, phantomjs_options: ["--load-images=no"])
end
```

That way, it doesn't make those requests and doesn't trigger those errors.

Presumably the old version of Capybara or Poltergeist swallowed this type of error in some way – maybe by not loading images, maybe in some other way.

This isn't an elegant solution, but it seems no worse than whatever implicit swallowing happened before.